# Cocoapods commands fail due to "No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Users/<username>/.cocoapods/repos (Errno::ENOENT)"

Tags: cocoapods

Can anyone help me resolve the error in the stack trace below? This occurs when I run any `pod` command. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the gem with no luck.

```
00:44:05-David~/dev/farecast-app (master)$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb:422:in `open': No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Users/David/.cocoapods/repos (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb:422:in `foreach'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb:422:in `children'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:63:in `all'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:127:in `repo_information'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:63:in `report_error'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:300:in `handle_exception'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:264:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.4/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

*UPDATE*: Fixed with @KeithSmiley's suggestion.

Comment: Can you try removing `~/.cocoapods` with `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and running `pod setup` again.

Comment: @KeithSmiley I tried that and still get the same stacktrace from above when running any `pod` command, including `pod setup`.

Comment: Well instead of running `pod setup` you can manually clone the [specs repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/specs/) into `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`. Then you should be able to skip this step.

Comment: I was using 'git rm -rf Pods', but git doesn't actually removes the directory. For those who are stucked with this, do 'rm -rf Pods' and then 'pod install'.

Comment: Why don't you select the answer with 440+ upvotes?

Answer (score 484):

**If the message says you are missing a lib:**

I got same problem and it was fixed after running `pod setup` and then `pod install`

**If the missing directory is the ruby dir you can do:**

You have probably updated your osx or ruby gem recently and its PATH is still linking to the old ruby version. Fix with:

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ruby`

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

[As said by @rendel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394218/1713345)

Comment: Wondering why this isn't mentioned in the CocoaPods' getting started guide

Comment: Its a fixed bug, we're just waiting on getting the next version out

Answer (score 48):

[Cocoapods had an issue](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/) where their github repository had become corrupted, and this forces users to clean up their local repo manually.

A quote from the [Cocoapods blog post detailing the error](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/):

> *Unfortunately we've encountered a bug in libgit2 and we are going to
> have to force push into the Specs repository. (Also known as the
> ‘master’ spec repo.)*
>
> ***What does this mean for you? Well, basically your CocoaPods setup is
> going to break.** You are going to have to manually delete any local
> copies of the Specs repository and re-clone the new version of the
> Specs repository. You can do that with the following commands:*

### The Solution:

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ pod setup
```

Simply running the commands above will remove the corrupted repo and reinitialize using a clean repo. See [the blogpost mentioned above](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/) for more information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3783005, if you are getting that error, then it means that cocoapods is either not installed, or the executable 'pods' can't be found anywhere on your `PATH` variable. use `echo $PATH` to print out your full path to start the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 20):

I had similar issue. I deleted Pods folder and run pod install again. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for this ! You saved me some precious times :)

Answer (score 20):

Nothing worked for me, I had to `sudo gem install cocoapods` and that did the magic.

Comment: I had to do this after completing a migration via Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 10):

Tried a ton of stuff and the only fix for me was saying

```
brew install cocoapods
```

and then

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: This worked for me after I messed up my install somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sometimes occurs when using a wrong apostrophe character in a Podfile or in a Podspec

[image]

Those apostrophes are default when using standard TextEdit app on OS X.
I prefer Sublime Text to avoid such errors

Comment: Keep in mind, that when using 'private specs' technique, cocoapods may copy your local private Podspec into a directory called "./Your_Private_Subspec_Name/Pods/Local Podspecs". So, after fixing the original podspec you better delete those "Local Podspecs" directories, because cocoapods may not update the copies correctly

Answer (score 4):

**QUICK SOLUTION**

A **good way** to solve this issue is going to the specified folder and check for the file that is missing (sometimes it is there but in a rare format) and **delete** the file. Remove also `Podfile.lock` file

Then execute `pod install` and everything should be fine :) you don't need to remove all repos that Cocoapods have downloaded.

**Done!**

Comment: THIS. This is the fix. Reinstalled cocoapods, linked, all kinds of stuff and nothing worked until I went into Finder and deleted the files inside the pod that was mad. Even my own answer from 2018 O.o

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I ran into this issue on a fresh install of cocoapods. Sounds like it's a bug that is fixed in 0.36

https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues/58

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error. And I tried "pod setup", not working. Then I create a fake file which I was told missing, and then "pod update", works.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I had to delete whole ./Pods/ directory in my project to be able to continue (the directory contained symlinks to files from other branch that were not deleted on branch switch)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I ran into this problem when moving or deleting a .h file in a local pod. Turns out this was an issue with v0.38 and the solution was to update.

See the Github issue discussion of it [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3914).

Answer (score 0):

go to project directory and type command export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin