# Cocoa pod: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I have already a projects in which `cocoapod` was working fine previously but somehow now when I am trying to include new file. I am getting below error.

> /Users/username/.podenv/libexec/../libexec/podenv-exec: line 31: /Users/username/.podenv/versions/1.0.1/bin/pod: No such file or directory

I was trying to delete `MyProject.xcworkspace` and `Podfile` so that I can reinstall `Podfile` but again getting above error.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990057/cocoapods-commands-fail-due-to-no-such-file-or-directory-dir-initialize-us

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you somehow deleted the `cocoapods` itself rather then project and `Podfile` of specific project, kindly re install the `cocoapods` by following below commands:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Enter command:

   ```
   $ sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
3. Create new Xcode project.
4. Navigate to directory containing Xcode project. Use:

   ```
    cd ../directory-location/..
   ```

   or cd [drag-and-drop project folder]
5. Enter command to create the `Podfile`:

   ```
   $ pod init
   ```
6. Enter command

   ```
   $ pod install
   ```